# R dice support problem

Tags: r, probability, dice

Could someone please help me with the code for the following problem (I am brand new to R so it is being a bit complicated for me):

Consider the variable X, the sum of three, fair, 8-sided dice rolled once. What is the support of X? (The ''support' is the set of values that can be taken with non-0 probability)

Comment: I know it would somewhat involve the following line of code:                                                sum(sample(1:8, size = 3, replace = TRUE))

Comment: Hint: this isn't a question about how to use software, it's about the definition that you have in parenthesis.

Comment: I suppose I have to figure out the set of values that can be taken with non-0 probability. however, I do not know how to do so in R :(

Comment: **This isn't about how to use R.** Can you roll three 8-sided dice (numbered 1,2,3,...,8) and get -10? 1500? 7? 3.7? Which values is it possible to roll?

Comment: I understand that. Is there any function in R that allows you to get the given set of values? Or anyway in which I could somehow get those set of values? If I run sum(sample(1:8, size = 3, replace = TRUE))  I would get one of the possible values, and of course, they will not be -10, 1500, 7 or 3.7. However, the question is asking me for the whole set of possible values, not one by one.

Comment: Are you sure that 7 is impossible? What's 1 + 2 + 4?

Comment: Sorry, yes 7 is possible. But once again, my question is: "is there any way that I could get the whole set of values that are possible with the givens using R?"

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: @JairMoreira If how to use R is central to your question, you should clarify that in your question. As your question reads right now, you don't ask how to determine the support in R. You just ask what the support is.

Comment: I am so sorry @Sycorax yes that would be my question. And thank you for the clarification Stephan Kolassa. I am self-learning in order to prepare myself for graduate school. So yeah what I had done so far is generated the random dices with their sum. I am not sure how to get the support using R. Once I finished that I will run a mean over the set, then an SD and then apply a rnorm all which I know how to use in R. I am just very lost regarding the support. Thank you

Comment: Although it can be done in `R`, you would be much better off solving problems without insisting on using software to solve them.  Here is one solution that generalizes nicely, as the final two lines ought to suggest: `die <- function(n) {d <- c(0, 1:n/n); class(d) <- "die"; d};
support <- function(x) which(x > 0) - 1;
'+.die' <- function(x, y) zapsmall(convolve(x, rev(y), type="open"));
d8 <- die(8);
support(d8 + d8 + d8)`

Comment: `unique(apply(expand.grid(1:8, 1:8, 1:8), 1, sum))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you could do this:

First, you could simply create a 512x3 matrix and populate it with all the possible combinations of die rolls using 3 for loops (2 of which are nested).  After you have all of the possible combinations simply add up the rows.  You will then have to get the support from this by removing all of the duplicate (or triplicate etc.) values

Second, you could use the code you already wrote sum(sample(1:8, size = 3, replace = TRUE)) but wrap it in a for loop and repeat the process a large amount of times, storing the results in a vector.  If you repeat it enough times you should get all the possible values.  Then once again you just need to find a way to get a vector of unique values from this.